# Memcache city lookup table or not

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

I have just purchased the following database table(s) so that our users can select which city around the world they are in:

http://www.rocky.nu/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=4&products_id=13

Although it works very well, it is a bit slow and we anticipate all our users to use it. I have read up on memcache and was wondering whether it would be a good idea to memcache all queries to this database therefore if users from the same city access the site it will increase performance to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `it is a bit slow` doesn't help much.  What's slow about it?

Comment: @G-Nugget Slow is the wrong word, I meant that I wanted to optimize it further if possible

Comment: @Aftab - what columns are you searching by?  Seems like with only 148,000 records it should be pretty fast if everything is indexed correctly.

Comment: Eric beat me to the point about searching, but the data types could also be improved.

Comment: @EricPetroelje Basically the user selects their country via a dropdown box which auto-populates the next couple of dropdown boxes via the country id. I was wondering whether I could further optimize the process by memcache's the city lookup per country. Therefore if someone selects United Kingdom, the next x amount of users from the United Kingdom for the next 24 hours can retrieve the cities form memcache rather than the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: @G-Nugget Oh really, what would you recommend?

Comment: What is the query you're using?  If it's more than just `SELECT * FROM geo_cities WHERE con_id = x`, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're searching through the tables by location or names, there isn't a lot you can do.  As I mentioned in my comment above, the data types of the ID columns should not be `BIGINT`s; `MEDIUM INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL` would be better and the higher level indexes could be made `SMALL INT`s or `TINY INT`s if you're feeling adventurous.

Getting the cities from a country ID or state ID should be virtually instant.  If you want to search by lat/lon you should use spatial stuff, but that gets somewhat complex if you're not familiar with it.

P.S. I'm assuming the indexes shown on the store page made it into your database.

Comment: Ok thanks I will have a go at these. I guess what I am trying to figure out is whether it would make sense to store the cities of a country in memcache rather than going back to the database. Guess I will have to do some benchmarking and figure this out that way

Comment: @AftabChoudhry Yeah, I guess I got a bit off topic.  A database is a better storage solution and there should not be any performance issues since you're working with a relatively small data set and using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about memcache, but make sure you have an index key on the highest searched column. And if there is a unique field, unique key that column as well.